# unable to access the value from xaml.cs to scheduletaskagent.cs in windows phone 7.1 application

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

Am trying to build a window phone 7.1 application where in am getting a username from db to my xaml.cs file through webservice. Now, I need to access that username to scheduledtaskagent(backgroundprocess). am unable to achieve it even if I used PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["username"] to store my variable value.
the following is my code for xaml.cs file:

```
  private void tservice_InsertUserCompleted(object sender, UTservice.InsertUserCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result != string.Empty)
        {

            username = e.Result.ToString();
            PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["uname"] = username;
            StartPeriodicAgent();

        }

    }
```

the below is the code in scheduledtaskagent.cs

```
 protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
        string uname;
        uname = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["uname"].ToString();
    }
```

am getting a "NullReference" exception in the above statement.

Could someone please let me know the way out to reslove my issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `PhoneApplicationService.Current.State` is local to the process; AFAIK, you cannot pass values to the background agent directly!

You can however, save some info to a file in IsolatedStorage, and when the agent runs read that file contents and use it somehow!